# How to get the bonded data from the Model to the code behind

Tags: php, json, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a separate model to get the ticket id from the SQLserver as below (I am getting data from PHP as json object)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestProject.Data
{
    public class TiketViewModel
    {
        public int TiketNumb { get; set; }
        public int FlagNum { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonTicketNewNum
    {
        public List<TiketViewModel>TicketInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I get the data through the model by using post async (I am sending the location id and table id as inputs to retrieve the ticket id from the sql server)

```
public async void GetTicketinfo()
{
    string LocationId = "1";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LocationId", LocationId));
    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TableID", count));////////
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
    // var response = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.43.226/GetTicket.php", content);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(Constants.BaseUrlpos + "GetTicket.php", content);
    string JsonTiket = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    // string JsonTikettwo = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    // TicketModel ObjContactList = new TicketModel();
    TiketViewModel ObjContactList = new TiketViewModel();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonTiket);
        var items = ObjContactList.TiketNumb;
        var itemstwo = ObjContactList.FlagNum;
    }
```

My problem is how do I access in the code behind `TiketNumb` and `FlagNum` through the model data set to the data that O retrieve? Because there is an exception through in `Issucessstatuscode`.  Thanks in advance for your support.
Pan

Answer (score 0):

I would change the code a little.  I would check is the response IsSuccessStatusCode before I read the content

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(Constants.BaseUrlpos + "GetTicket.php", content);

// string JsonTikettwo = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
// TicketModel ObjContactList = new TicketModel();
TiketViewModel ObjContactList = new TiketViewModel();
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   string JsonTiket = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TiketViewModel>(JsonTiket);
   var items = ObjContactList.TiketNumb;
   var itemstwo = ObjContactList.FlagNum;
}
```

Comment: I tryied your method but there is an error in visual studio " Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'TestProject.Data.TiketViewModel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) " so i am clue less what to do

Comment: I made an edit to the code so it Deserializes a strongly typed TiketViewModel